# Complexity of a very simple graph partitioning problem

Tags: graph-theory, computational-complexity, partitions

The following problem seems like a very simple and natural one, but I am not familiar with any existing work on it; in particular I am hoping to prove it is NP hard:

Let $G$ be a complete weighted graph that satisfies a triangle inequality, let $k \geq 2$ be an integer, and let $r>0$.  My goal is to partition the vertices of $G$ into $k$ subsets $G_1,\dots,G_k$ with the following property:  if we select *any* set of $k$ vertices $v_1,\dots,v_k$, with $v_i \in G_i$ for all $i$, and we let $S$ be the subgraph on the $v_i$'s consisting of edges with weights less than $r$, then we want $S$ to be connected.  Thus, we're looking for a $k$-way partition that is "connected with radius $r$".

Does this ring any bells?  I would think that one could prove that this is NP-hard by, say, a reduction to a maximum covering problem or a $k$-centers problem, but my attempts have been unsuccessful so far.  The problem as stated is a feasibility question because we are given $k$ and $r$, but it could also be made into an optimization problem by fixing one parameter and searching for the minimum possible value of the other.

Comment: You are going to need r big enough so that such a decomposition is remotely possible.  I'm thinking that the subgraph T_r of G which contains only edges of length less than r has to be k-connected or something along those lines.  Are there quick ways to determine if T_r "might be connected enough"?  Gerhard "Maybe A Simpler Hard Problem" Paseman, 2015.09.09

Comment: In particular, if G has a vertex v with distance greater than r to all other vertices, then v can't belong to any of the k subsets.  Are you promising anything with respect to r, or is an additional goal to find a minimal such r?  Gerhard "The Problem Behind The Problem?" Paseman, 2015.09.09

Comment: @GerhardPaseman, sure, the problem as stated is a feasibility problem, but one could certainly search for the minimal $r$ that ensures connectivity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $k=2$, it's polynomial (in fact quadratic in the number of vertices). Draw an edge (in an auxiliary graph) between two vertices iff their distance is greater than $r$ (marking that these two vertices must be in the same part). Then you can partition the graph into two sets if and only if the auxiliary graph is disconnected.